# Start an application silently with "AsyncNoWait"?

Tags: rest, asynchronous, wix, silent-installer

I am trying to build an installer that will start a REST service (win32 console application) after installation silently.

I have did a lot of permutations, and can get some result, however I can't get what I want.
Here is a list of test cases:

1. With Filekey I can launch the application, but with console.
2. With "`BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="CAQuietExec"`" I can run the application silently, but it is not asynchronous. The installer will stop and wait, and, with property, deferred custom action.

Can anybody help me figure this out?

Comment: You need a Return=asyncNowait. Is this a production service? If so, is it supposed to start after a reboot? And if it's running on a server when nobody logs in it won't start at all unless it's a Windows service.

Comment: Thank you, it is a process, I only need it to start when user logged in. and the first time they install it. It is a local server that listening request from chrome and run some C++ code. I am doing this because Google is deprecating the NPAPI but I need the plugin to call native code.

Answer (score 0):

To run an installer silently I use /qn in the command line.
So this looks something like:

```
msiexec /i <installername> /qn /l*v install.log
```

With this command the installer will run silently, without bringing up the UI. The customaction may be set such that it starts the REST service as part of the installation process. The install.log file that will be created in the same location where the installer exists is the log file for the installation.

I maybe able to help if you may share the exact command and parameters that has to be run to start the REST process.